# -bash ruby command not found

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

Every time I log into my VPS I must run `source ~/.bashrc` before I can run any `rvm`, `ruby`, or `gem` commands.

Why is this? Can't make it load by default?

```
ssh deployer@xxx
ruby -v
-bash: ruby: command not found
source ~/.bashrc
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [i686-linux]
```

I installed rvm under `deployer`.

I have `~/.bash_pofile` which is empty. I also have `~/.profile` which has the following in it:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

My `~/.bashrc` has this at the top:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

So in your case, the (empty) `~/.bash_profile` is being executed, and your `~/.profile` (and thus your `~/.bashrc`) are ignored.  To solve this, you'll either need to delete your `~/.bash_profile`, or else move the contents of `~/.profile` into `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 3):

When you log in, if Bash can find a file named `.bash_profile` in your home directory it will execute it and do not even search for a `.profile` file. Thus you have two choices, either remove the empty `.bash_profile` file or copy the contents of `.profile` to `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the information from `.bashrc` to the other files, as suggested by others is one way to do it.

Otherwise, this snippet of code will do the same thing, without needing to move the contents, or remove the file.  Depending on the ways you have things set up, you may not want to delete a file, if it has relevant information in it for other tasks, other than interactive login.

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Though using the files as they are intended to be used by reading the documentation can definitely alleviate some frustration.